# ActiveRecord: clever ways to round robin paginated query results by day

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

Suppose I have n database entries and want to display a subset of 10 that refreshes each day, cycling back to the beginning once it runs out of entries.

One method I came up with is using the day of the month as offset:

```
limit = 10
day = DateTime.now.strftime("%d").to_i
offset = (day - 1) * limit
Article.order("published_at DESC").offset(offset).limit(limit)
```

But: this quickly gets messy once you start to consider that, for instance, if I only have 65 entries I'll only display 5 items on day 7, and zero the following days (thus having to get the offset back to zero).

Comment: I think you need a solution that's a bit less clever with just a attribute/column on Article that tells you whether that article has been shown. Then select a random 10 from the rest.

Comment: `Article.where(displayed: false).pluck(:id).sample(10)` will give you a random 10 articles

Comment: And when I run out of articles, all of them go back to displayed:false. Good one, I'll try it.